# Getting Connection refused from redis cloud spring boot integration

Tags: java, caching, redis

I am getting below error

> org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis] with root cause
>
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

below is my code

application.properties

```
# Redis Configuration
spring.cache.type=redis
spring.redis.host=redis-14218.c301.ap-south-1-1.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com
spring.redis.port=14218
spring.redis.password=***
spring.redis.database=0
```

my Application.Java

```
package com.serverless.serverlessapi;

import java.time.Duration;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.RedisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair;

    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableCaching
    public class Application {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }
    
        @Bean
        public RedisCacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration() {
            return RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
              .entryTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(60))
              .disableCachingNullValues()
              .serializeValuesWith(SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer()));
        }
        
        @Bean
        public RedisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer redisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer() {
            return (builder) -> builder
              .withCacheConfiguration("leads",
                RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().entryTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(10)))
              .withCacheConfiguration("leadsCahce2",
                RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().entryTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(5)));
        }
        
    }
```

my RestController

```
package com.serverless.serverlessapi.rest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.serverless.serverlessapi.services.LeadsService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class LeadsRestController {
    
    @Autowired
    private LeadsService leadsService;

    @Cacheable(value = "leads")
    @GetMapping("/leads2")
    public String getAllLeads2(@RequestParam(name = "limit") int limit, @RequestParam(name = "skip") int skip){
        try {
            return leadsService.getAllLeads2(limit,skip);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "data not found, please contact to admin";
    }
    
}
```

> I have also enbled the redis db
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etAAu.png)